# How to return custom JSON after successful sign_in in devise_token_auth gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, devise

I am creating a rails API using **[devise_token_auth gem](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth)**. I want not just the token in header that this gem returns after successful sign_in but also some table associated with user.

How can I send custom JSON after successful sign_in from devise_token auth gem overriding the default JSON response?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it my-self.

First in `config/routes.rb` I added the custom sessions controller:

```
mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', skip: [:omniauth_callbacks], controllers: { registrations: "registrations", sessions: "sessions" }
```

Then created a file called `app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb` and added following content:

```
class SessionsController < DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController
  def render_create_success
    render "users/success"
  end
end
```

Then I created a file named `app/views/users/success.json.jbuilder` and added the json data like this:

```
json.data @resource
json.groups @resource.groups do |group|
  json.id group.id
  json.name group.name
end
```

So by that I can give the custom JSON after successful login.

Comment: Nice and clean. In my case, I just used the existing user views: `render @resource, location: @resource`

Answer (score 12):

In User model create a method "**token_validation_response**".
Example:

```
def token_validation_response
  {test: 'this is custom data'}
end
```

Or if you want to add a custom field, you can do it like this:

```
  def as_json(options={})
    super(options).merge({test: 'this is custom field'})
  end
```

Comment: The overriding of "token_validation_response" worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Where should this function def as_json(options={}) be placed?

Comment: @Kiong in your model

Comment: This answer is much simpler than the accepted answer. `token_validation_response` in the User model is perfect, thank you.